# Spark SQL - How to write DataFrame to text file?

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I am using `Spark SQL` for reading parquet and writing parquet file.

But some cases,i need to write the `DataFrame` as text file instead of Json or Parquet.

Is there any default methods supported or i have to convert that DataFrame to `RDD` then use `saveAsTextFile()` method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using [Databricks Spark-CSV](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) you can save directly to a CSV file and load from a CSV file afterwards like this

> ```
> import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
>
> SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
> DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
>     .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
>     .option("inferSchema", "true")
>     .option("header", "true")
>     .load("cars.csv");
>
> df.select("year", "model").write()
>     .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
>     .option("header", "true")
>     .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
>     .save("newcars.csv");
> ```

Comment: should it be `df.select("year", "model").write.format` instead of `df.select("year", "model").write().format` ? Else you get a `TypeError: 'DataFrameWriter' object is not callable` error

Comment: This is the official example provided for Spark 1.3. If you use Spark 1.4+ you should use `df.select("year", "model").write.format` as you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

```
df.repartition(1).write.option("header", "true").csv("filename.csv")
```