# Issue with Spark-Sql while splitting data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am testing some basic queries from spark-1.5.1 on casandra 2.1.12. Having this wired issue when i try to split the data by '=' i.e. action column in the table. It parses correctly where as in case of '|'. It returns the individual character. Why is it so.

Moreover, value of action column is not shown completely. So, how do view complete value of column on stdout.

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext
    import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
    import org.apache.spark.sql

    val csc = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)
    csc.setKeyspace("test")

    val maxDF = csc.sql("select action, split(action, '=')[0], split(action, '=')[1], split(action, '=')[2] from testdata" )

    maxDF.show
```

**Output of Splitting '='**

```
    scala> maxDF.show
    +--------------------+------+-----------+---------+
    |              action|   _c1|        _c2|      _c3|
    +--------------------+------+-----------+---------+
    | car=10.288|city=262|   car|10.288|city|      262|
    |kms=0-|year=0-|bu...|   kms|    0-|year|0-|budget|
    |city=40|pc=40|car=10|  city|      40|pc|   40|car|
    |city=40|pc=40|car...|  city|      40|pc|   40|car|
    |city=40|pc=40|car...|  city|      40|pc|   40|car|
    |                pn=1|    pn|          1|     null|
    | city=10|pc=10|car=9|  city|      10|pc|   10|car|
    |city=10|pc=10|car...|  city|      10|pc|   10|car|
    |city=10|pc=10|car...|  city|      10|pc|   10|car|
    |city=10|pc=10|car...|  city|      10|pc|   10|car|
    |city=10|pc=10|car...|  city|      10|pc|   10|car|
    |  city=10|pc=10|pn=1|  city|      10|pc|    10|pn|
    |   year=0-|so=1|sc=0|  year|      0-|so|     1|sc|
    |year=0-|so=1|sc=0...|  year|      0-|so|     1|sc|
    |             year=8-|  year|         8-|     null|
    |budget=6-12|city=...|budget|  6-12|city|    10|pc|
    |budget=6-12|city=...|budget|  6-12|city|    10|pc|
    |budget=6-12|city=...|budget|  6-12|city|    10|pc|
    |budget=6-12|city=...|budget|  6-12|city|    10|pc|
    |car=9.266|city=24...|   car| 9.266|city|   246|pc|
    +--------------------+------+-----------+---------+
    only showing top 20 rows
```

**Output of splitting '|'**

```
val maxDF = csc.sql("select action, split(action, '|')[0], split(action, '|')[1], split(action, '|')[2] from testdata" )

    maxDF.show

    +--------------------+---+---+---+
    |              action|_c1|_c2|_c3|
    +--------------------+---+---+---+
    | car=10.288|city=262|   |  c|  a|
    |kms=0-|year=0-|bu...|   |  k|  m|
    |city=40|pc=40|car=10|   |  c|  i|
    |city=40|pc=40|car...|   |  c|  i|
    |city=40|pc=40|car...|   |  c|  i|
    |                pn=1|   |  p|  n|
    | city=10|pc=10|car=9|   |  c|  i|
    |city=10|pc=10|car...|   |  c|  i|
    |city=10|pc=10|car...|   |  c|  i|
    |city=10|pc=10|car...|   |  c|  i|
    |city=10|pc=10|car...|   |  c|  i|
    |  city=10|pc=10|pn=1|   |  c|  i|
    |   year=0-|so=1|sc=0|   |  y|  e|
    |year=0-|so=1|sc=0...|   |  y|  e|
    |             year=8-|   |  y|  e|
    |budget=6-12|city=...|   |  b|  u|
    |budget=6-12|city=...|   |  b|  u|
    |budget=6-12|city=...|   |  b|  u|
    |budget=6-12|city=...|   |  b|  u|
    |car=9.266|city=24...|   |  c|  a|
    +--------------------+---+---+---+
```

Comment: maybe try split(action,"\=") or something similar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vertical pipe "|" separates a series of alternatives, and in your case there are no alternatives so it simply returns the longest matching pattern from that character own, which is the character.

Use `split(action, '\\|')`

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what do you mean by `series of alternatives`. I am new to spark. So, not aware or it. Moreover, how to view the complete value of column. Currently we see `...` for lengthy string. Also, can we write this output to a file also i.e. csv or any other format

Comment: `'\\|'` has the same problem for me. I had to use `'\\\\|'`

Comment: @Naresh [Alternatives in regex pattern](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). For the second part is just how it is displayed. the `sql` call returns a `DataFrame`, so you can use [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010984/spark-sql-how-to-write-dataframe-to-text-file/36011735#36011735) to save to csv

Answer (score 1):

`split(action, '\\|')` still has the same problem for me. I had to use `split(action, '\\\\|')`